# Can't exit from a TextField flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I need of a Box where insert and store some informations that comes as user input, I'm using the 'TextField' so I changed the 'maxLines' option in my 'TextField' from default value (1) to (2) and when I want to insert some text here I can't leave the box because the 'Done' button changed to 'return' blocking me! The keyboard is blocked too.
I'm doing this because I would like a Box with some text inside (like a description) that I can move where I want and change all its properties.
My issue is that the textfield writes all in one line, I need of a newline at the border of the textfield.
Do you know how to handle the TextField better?
This is a part of the code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body : Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: _image == null
                ? AssetImage('assets/images/io.png')
                : FileImage(_image),  // here add your image file path,
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
         ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child:Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child : ConstrainedBox(
             constraints: BoxConstraints(
               maxHeight: 400,
               maxWidth: 400,
                ),
              child: TextField(
                minLines: 1,
                 maxLines: 2,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                       const Radius.circular(48.0)
                    ),
                  ),
                labelText: 'Descrizione',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    )
);
```

P.S.: I'm studying this 'GestureDetector', it should be useful for this purpose I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In the `TextField` go into `InputDecoration` and add a Widget to the suffix property . The suffix property is a Widget that shows at the end of the `Textfield`.

```
FocusNode node = FocusNode();


TextField(
                minLines: 1,
                maxLines: 2,
                focusNode: node,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffix: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      node.unfocus();
                    },
                    child: Text("Done"),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(48.0)),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Descrizione',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```